# FEM: Electric Field between two arbitrary defined shapes

Tags: finite-element-method, electromagnetics

I was wondering how to do the following:
I would like to compute the electrostatic field between two shapes using the FEM method.

```
(*Define Boundaries*)
air = Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}];
object1 = Disk[];
object2 = Rectangle[{2, 0}, {2.5, 2}];
Show[Graphics[{Blue, air}], Graphics[{Magenta, object1}],Graphics[{Green, object2}]]
```

[image]

Calculation of the electric field at every point {x,y} in 2D space:

[image]
$r_i$ is the vector of the point charge; $r$ is the vector to the point in 2D (or also 3D) space where we want to calculate the electric field.

I make a Mathematica function out of it (for the moment I omit the constant term):

```
eField[x_, y_] := q Sum[({x, y} - pts[[i]])/Norm[{x, y} - pts[[i]]]^3, {i, n}]
```

where  `pts[[i]]` are the boundary points of the charged object and `x` and `y` are coordinates of the "air" object.

**How I would proceed:**

1. I calculate the electrostatic field of object 1 -> $E_1$
2. I calculate the electrostatic field of object 1 -> $E_2$
3. I use superposition to get the resultant electric field: $E_{Total} = E_1 +E_2$

   ```
   Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

   r1 = RegionDifference[air, object1];
   r2 = RegionDifference[air, object2];
   mesh1 = ToElementMesh[r1];
   mesh2 = ToElementMesh[r2];
   mesh1["Wireframe"]
   mesh2["Wireframe"]
   ```

[image]

**I would really appreciate if someone could show me how to do it in Mathematica using finite elements (FEM).**

**EDIT:** 
Basend on the excellent answer below, I would like to use the answer here [Get Perimeter Region from Object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218899/get-perimeter-region-from-object/218901#218901) to automate the finding of the region boundaries for the `DirichletCondition`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(*Define Boundaries*)
air = Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}];
object1 = Disk[];
object2 = Rectangle[{-2.5, -2.5}, {2.5, -2}];
reg12 = RegionUnion[object1, object2];
reg = RegionDifference[air, reg12]

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.001 (0.1 + 10 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]
mesh["Wireframe"]

eq = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]; V1 = 1; V2 = -2;
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V1, 
    Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object1], {x, y}, 
       "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V2, 
    Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object2], {x, y}, 
       "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]]};
U = NDSolveValue[{eq == 0, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];

ef = -Grad[U[x, y], {x, y}];

DensityPlot[U[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}]

StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate[ef], {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {x, y}, StreamStyle -> LightGray, VectorPoints -> Fine,
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2.5, 3}}]
```

[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2:** 
Just for beauty:  **Parallel Plate Capacitor**
Use this answer to make it work: [FEM Simulation: Meshing two Arbitrary objects in an "air" mesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218903/fem-simulation-meshing-two-arbitrary-objects-in-an-air-mesh/218909#218909)

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/208604/18437) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207366/18437)

Comment: @james The solution depends on the electrical conductivity of the disk and the rectangle. There is one solution for a conductor, and another for a dielectric.

Comment: The comment of @AlexTrounev **is** very important. Are the disk and the rectangle conductor ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  here on MSE, there is a recurrent problem of confusion between 1) dielectric versus conductor 2) potential imposed at boundary versus presence of charges. I give up, though if you want to explain the things, I could do an effort to participate. The problem is not related to Mma but some people think the Mathematica+FEM will solve all this magically.

Comment: One point more : The formula above giving the electrical field E=..r/r^3 is wrong in the 2D case. In the 2D case it is E=..r/r^2. I have already seen this error on MSE too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the case of two metal objects, we can set the potential of each object as $V_1, V_2$. Then the code for a numerical solution in 2D is

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(*Define Boundaries*)air = Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}];
object1 = Disk[];
object2 = Rectangle[{2, 0}, {2.5, 2}]; reg12 = 
 RegionUnion[object1, object2];
reg = RegionDifference[air, reg12];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.001 (0.1 + 10 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]
mesh["Wireframe"]
eq = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]; V1 = 1; V2 = -2;
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V1, x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y] == 
     V2, (x == 2 || x == 2.5 && 0 <= y <= 2) || (y == 0 || 
       y == 2 && 2 <= x <= 2.5)]};
U = NDSolveValue[{eq == 0, bc}, u, {x, y} ∈ mesh];

ef = -Grad[U[x, y], {x, y}];
```

Visualisation of solution

```
{DensityPlot[U[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}], 
 StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate[ef], {x, y} ∈ reg, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {x, y}, StreamStyle -> LightGray, 
  VectorPoints -> Fine, PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-1, 3}}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. Next code is devoted to solve electrostatic problem for combination of dielectric and conducting objects (glass cylinder and metal strip). For dielectric we  put electric charge $q_1$, and for metal we put potential $V_2$. Code:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
par = {eps1 -> 3.5, eps2 -> 1.0}; air = 
 Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}];
object1 = Disk[]; q1 = 1; vol1 = 
 NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ object1]; rho1 = q1/vol1;
object2 = Rectangle[{2, 0}, {2.5, 2}]; 
rho[x_, y_] := rho1 Boole[{x, y} ∈ object1];
eps[x_, y_] := 
 eps2 + (eps1 - eps2) Boole[{x, y} ∈ object1]; reg = 
 RegionDifference[air, object2];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.001 (0.1 + 10 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]
mesh["Wireframe"]
 V2 = -2; eq = 
 Inactive[Div][
   eps[x, y] Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == -2 Pi rho[x, 
    y]; bc = 
 DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V2, {x, y} ∈ object2];
U = NDSolveValue[{eq /. par, bc}, u, {x, y} ∈ mesh];

ef = -Grad[U[x, y], {x, y}];
```

Visualisation

```
{DensityPlot[U[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}], 
 StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate[ef], {x, y} ∈ reg, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {x, y}, StreamStyle -> LightGray, 
  VectorPoints -> Fine, PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-1, 3}}], 
 StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate[ef], {x, y} ∈ reg, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, StreamStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106366/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-trounev-fem-electric-field-between-two-arbitrary-d).

Comment: [2nd chatroom (created before the one linked just above)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53995706#53995706)