# Get Perimeter Region from Object

Tags: graphics, regions

I can get the region of a disk $\{x,y\}\in\{x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$ as follows:

```
Region[Disk[]]
```

[image]

Now my question is: Is there also an automated way to get the perimeter region ?

$$\{x,y\}\in\{x^2+y^2=1\}$$

Many thanks !

Comment: `RegionBoundary[Region[Disk[]]]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** Composing `RegionMember`, `RegionBoundary` and `FullSimplify`:

```
ClearAll[boundaryRF]
boundaryRF = FullSimplify[RegionMember[RegionBoundary @ #, #2], #2 ∈ Reals] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Grid[{#, boundaryRF[#, {x, y}]} & /@ 
   {Disk[], Disk[{a, b}, r], Rectangle[], Triangle[]}, 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{#, boundaryRF[#, {x, y, z}]} & /@ 
   {Ball[], Ball[{a, b, c}, r], Tetrahedron[], Cone[]}, 
  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]
**Original answer:**

For `Disk` yes:

```
RegionBoundary[Disk[]]
```

> ```
> Circle[{0, 0}]
> ```

```
RegionMember[%, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> (x | y) ∈ Reals && x^2 + y^2 == 1
> ```

Works with symbolic parameters too:

```
RegionBoundary[Disk[{a, b}, r]]
```

> ```
> Circle[{a, b}, r]
> ```

```
RegionMember[%, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> (x | y) ∈ Reals && r > 0 && (-a + x)^2 + (-b + y)^2 == r^2
> ```

... and few other primitives:

```
RegionBoundary[Ball[]]
```

> ```
>  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]
> ```

```
RegionMember[%, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> (x | y | z) ∈ Reals && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1
> ```

```
RegionBoundary[Rectangle[]]
```

> ```
>  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]
> ```

```
RegionMember[%, {x, y}] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
>  (x | y) ∈ Reals && ((0 <= y <= 1 && (x == 0 || x == 1)) || (0 <= x <= 
>   1 && (y == 0 || y == 1)))
> ```

**Acknowledgement:** Thank you Chip Hurst for reminding me that we can use  [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html) instead of

```
Region`RegionProperty[%, {x, y}, "FastDescription"][[1, -1]]
```

to get the region function.

Comment: Very nice ! Thank you very much !! One question: when you type `Region\`RegionProperty[...` what does the `\`` stand for ?

Comment: @james, see [tutorial/Contexts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html)

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: @james, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Why not avoid the internal functions and use `RegionMember[RegionBoundary[Disk[]], {x, y}]`?

Comment: @ChipHurst, yes off course!. It just did not occur to me. Perhaps  you should  post that as an answer?

Comment: I think you should update your post to avoid one thinking an internal function is needed.

Comment: Thank you @ChipHurst. I updated.