# FEM: Getting Resulting Electric Force on each body from electric field

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-element-method, electromagnetics

Based on this excellent answer [FEM: Electric Field between two arbitrary defined shapes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218683/fem-electric-field-between-two-arbitrary-defined-shapes) I can compute the electric field `ef` between two conducting objects.

[image]

$$ F = qE$$
Now, I tried to compute the **total resultant electric force** on each object (acting at it´s geometric center), by simply integrating the electric field around the boundary of the object :

So according to the Mathematica Documentation, the correct way to specify a domain, is for example:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element]
```

ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1 [And] z == 0, {x, y, z}]]

Since

```
Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object1], {x, y}, 
         "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]
```

gives me the implicit region of the contour of object1, I can find the force as follows:

```
NIntegrate[
 Evaluate[ef], {x, y} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[
   Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object1], {x, y}, 
      "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]], {x, y}]]
```

Here is the full code to compute the electric field:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(*Define Boundaries*)
air = Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}];
object1 = Rectangle[{-2.5, 2.5}, {2.5, 2}];
object2 = Rectangle[{-2.5, -2.5}, {2.5, -2}];
reg12 = RegionUnion[object1, object2];
reg = RegionDifference[air, reg12]

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1];
mesh["Wireframe"]

eq = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]; V1 = 1; V2 = -2;
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V1, 
    Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object1], {x, y}, 
       "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V2, 
    Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object2], {x, y}, 
       "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]]};
U = NDSolveValue[{eq == 0, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];

ef = -Grad[U[x, y], {x, y}];



force1 = NIntegrate[
   Evaluate[ef], {x, y} \[Element] 
    ImplicitRegion[
     Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object1], {x, y}, 
        "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]], {x, y}]];



centroid1 = RegionCentroid[object1];



StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate[ef], {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {x, y}, StreamStyle -> LightGray, VectorPoints -> Fine,
  PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {{Arrow[{centroid1, centroid1 + force1}], 
    Text["Force", centroid1 + force1/2, Background -> LightRed]}}]
```

I get:

[image]

**My question is: Is this approach correct ? And if not: How would you do it ?**

Comment: Please describe what did not work and what you are expecting.

Comment: Read through the (`NIntegrate`, etc) references pages to see how regions are specified. Don't willy-nilly copy things that you do not know how to use and expect them to work. Please spend some time reading the documentation - it's good.

Comment: @user21 Thank you for that little "push". I checked the Documentation more carefully, and I have possibly found a solution. I would be pleased if you could have a look at my updated question. Many thanks !

Comment: @james Electrostatic force acting on a conductor is $\int {E^2/(8\pi)\vec {n}dS}$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you for your comment ? Do you have a reference for this ? If I put `Evaluate[ef^2]/(8*Pi)` into the integral I get a force, pointing upwards at an angle, which should not be the case.

Comment: @james This expression is in all textbooks on electromagnetic theory in the section Electrostatics. For instance,  Jackson, Classical Electrodynamics.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you very much ! Do you see, why I get an arrow pointing upwards and at an angle for this setup ?

Comment: @james There is a big error in corner points when calculating `ef` and $\vec {n}$

Comment: @AlexTrounev That´s annoying. :( How would you solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

Electrostatic force acting on a conductor in electric field is given by $\vec {F}=\int{\frac {E^2}{8\pi}\vec {n}dS}$. In this case we have a plate with normal vector $\vec {n}=(0,\pm 1)$ for upper and lower surfaces respectively. To calculate electric field we take `air` more wide and compute sufficient `mesh`:

```
 Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(*Define Boundaries*)
air = Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}];
object1 = Rectangle[{-2.5, 2.}, {2.5, 2.5}];
object2 = Rectangle[{-2.5, -2.5}, {2.5, -2}];
reg12 = RegionUnion[object1, object2];
reg = RegionDifference[air, reg12];

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.003 (0.1 + 10 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]
mesh["Wireframe"]
eq = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]; V1 = 1; V2 = -2;
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V1, 
    Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object1], {x, y}, 
       "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V2, 
    Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object2], {x, y}, 
       "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]]};
U = NDSolveValue[{eq == 0, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];

ef = -Grad[U[x, y], {x, y}];

force1 = -NIntegrate[Evaluate[ef.ef] /. y -> 2, {x, -2.5, 2.5}];
force1 = force1 + 
  NIntegrate[Evaluate[ef.ef] /. y -> 2.5, {x, -2.5, 2.5}];force=force1/(8 Pi);
centroid1 = RegionCentroid[object1];

StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate[ef], {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {x, y}, StreamStyle -> LightGray, VectorPoints -> Fine,
  PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {{Arrow[{centroid1, centroid1 + {0, force1}}], 
    Text["Force", centroid1 + {0, force1/2}, 
     Background -> LightRed]}}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I am impressed, as usually ! .. So, to me it seems that you are omitting the sides of the squares (because in this configuration the force are equal and opposite = cancel each other). Is my assumption correct ?

Comment: If I slightly misplace the top rectangle: `object1 = Rectangle[{-4.5, 2.}, {0.5, 2.5}]` Then it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Also, could it be that your formula for the electrostatic force is valid for 3D, but not 2D ? See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/541935/claculate-electrostatic-force/541937?noredirect=1#comment1225663_541937

Comment: @james Formula for force is same in 2D and 3D. There are several system of physical units including SI and CGS.Electrostatic force acting on conductor in electric field is $\vec {F}=k/2 \int_S E^2 \vec {n}dS $, where $k$ depends on units, for example, $k=1/(4\pi)$ in CGS and $k=\epsilon_0$ in SI.

Comment: For asymmetric case use also $F_x$ not only $F_y$ as in my solution.